# How to get the content from an HTTP POST request received in thin?

Tags: ruby, rack, thin

I am using thin to receive HTTP POST requests, my server code is this:

```
http_server = proc do |env|
  # Want to make response dependent on content
  response = "Hello World!"
  [200, {"Connection" => "close", "Content-Length" => response.bytesize.to_s}, [response]]
end
```

Setting a breakpoint, I can see that I have received the content-type (json), and content length, but can't see the actual content.  How can I retrieve the content from the request for processing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `rack.input` entry of the `env` object. From the [Rack Spec](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/SPEC.html):

> The input stream is an IO-like object which contains the raw HTTP POST data. When applicable, its external encoding must be “ASCII-8BIT” and it must be opened in binary mode, for Ruby 1.9 compatibility. The input stream must respond to `gets`, `each`, `read` and `rewind`.

So you can call `read` on it like this:

```
http_server = proc do |env|

  json_string = env['rack.input'].read
  json_string.force_encoding 'utf-8' # since the body has ASCII-8BIT encoding,
                                     # but we know this is json, we can use
                                     # force_encoding to get the right encoding

  # parse json_string and do your stuff

  response = "Hello World!"
  [200, {"Connection" => "close", "Content-Length" => response.bytesize.to_s}, [response]]
end
```